# java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFallbackFactory(CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:79)

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, weblogic12c, myfaces

I'm migrating a web application from weblogic 10 to weblogic 12 but I'm stuck with this problem.

```
<BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@494634632[app:portal-war-9.1.1 module:portal-war-9.1.1.war path:null spec-version:3.1]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFallbackFactory(CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:79)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:557)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:350)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.init(MyFacesServlet.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.getServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:304)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:246)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:246)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at pt.ptinovacao.components.aeolus.web.i18n.filter.AeolusI18nLocaleResolverFilter.doFilter(AeolusI18nLocaleResolverFilter.java:103)
    at pt.ptinovacao.components.aeolus.web.i18n.filter.AeolusI18nLocaleResolverFilter.doFilter(AeolusI18nLocaleResolverFilter.java:75)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at pt.ptinovacao.components.aeolus.jsf.web.security.AeolusTestPermissionFilter.doFilter(AeolusTestPermissionFilter.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at pt.ptinovacao.components.aeolus.web.context.filter.AeolusUserContextResolverFilter.doFilter(AeolusUserContextResolverFilter.java:103)
    at pt.ptinovacao.components.aeolus.web.context.filter.AeolusUserContextResolverFilter.doFilter(AeolusUserContextResolverFilter.java:75)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at pt.ptinovacao.portal.ui.filter.PerformanceFilter.doFilter(PerformanceFilter.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
>
```

The project originally designed for java 5 and has the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pt.ptinovacao.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>labelmask-custom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
        <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I already deployed both jsf and jstl 1.2 as a library on my server as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP206)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is that the COMPLETE stack trace with all "caused by" sections?  Is your code `pt.ptinovacao.components.aeolus.web.i18n.filter.AeolusI18nLocaleResolverFilter`?  That is the place to start looking.

Comment: Stack trace is irrelevant. Maven deps are clearly wrong. There are a lot of conflicting libraries there. Among others, OP is basically attempting to downgrade the server-provided servlet version back to 2.5. This makes no utter sense. Just it all straight based on the target server.